# Complex Generic Class Declaration

Tags: java, generics

This is simple dummy example to demonstrate problem.

We have following classes:

```java
public abstract class Engine { }

public class DieselEngine extends Engine { }
public class PetrolEngine extends Engine { }
```

Let's create some factories that produce engines:

```java
public abstract class EnginesFactory <T extends Engine> {

    public List<T> produceEngines() {
        return null;
    }
}

public class DieselEnginesFactory extends EnginesFactory <DieselEngine> { }
public class PertolEnginesFactory extends EnginesFactory <PetrolEngine> { }
```

**Question:**

How to create generic class that accepts *EngineFactory* subclasses ?
Something like that below which does not work, but is created to show my needs:

```java
public abstract class TestFactory <T extends EnginesFactory<R extends Engine>> { //R extends Engine is wrong

    public void testFactory(T factory) {
        testEngines(factory.produceEngines());
    }

    protected abstract void testEngines(List<R> engines);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare `R` as a second type parameter with its own bound, so that you can refer to `R` when declaring `T`.

```
public abstract class TestFactory<R extends Engine, T extends EnginesFactory<R>> {
```

(I assume you meant `public abstract class`, not `public class abstract`.)

Comment: Thank you! That is the right answer :) I also edited question to correct bug you found.